# php : Setting variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays

This is applicable in php

```
$a = [$a  = 2];

var_dump($a);
```

But what is the use of this syntax anyway ?

IMHO this syntax could introduce more bugs in the system so i think it would be better if its restricted

Answer (score 2):

There is no intention for such syntax. You can use any expression or assignment instead of an array element in PHP. PHP will calculate the result of expression and puts the result in array.

```
 $b=1;
 $a=[$b,$b+2,$b+$a,$a++,$a>$b,$c=$a+$b]
```

Comment: Should that be restricted so that many errors could have been prevented :)